# Parse error with date_modify

Tags: php

I've been struggling with some more complex code (for me) and my date manipulation has not been working (I'm trying to loop to create DB entries for Sundays for a Religious Education calendar).  It hasn't been going well.  I found great info here but not for this problem.  I stripped down my code to the VERY basic and STILL get the error "**Parse error: in /../test2.php on line 8**" (line 8 is the date_modify line).  Here is the code, with the function copied straight from PHP.net:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $date = date_create('2017-12-31');
    date_modify($date, '+7 day');  // this is line 8
    echo "Date = " . $date;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please add the full complete error message you get to your question. Also verify that the given PHP code above is the complete content of your PHP script.

Comment: There is nothing here that would cause a parse error (I checked) but `$date` is different from `$Date` in the `echo`.

Comment: PHP's variable names, object properties,  and array keys are case sensitive though class names and function names are _not_ case sensitive.

Comment: Progman: Other than taking out the full path of the error, that is the full error message.  And that IS the full code that produces the error.  That is what is so puzzling.

Comment: Michael: Exactly.  That is what I don't understand.  I did notice while I was reviewing this that the last $Date is different, but the code isn't event getting to that (obviously if it had, it would simply have shown "Date = " with no resulting value.  But due to the parse error, I don't get to that...

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2017-12-31');
date_modify($date, '+7 day');  // this is line 8
echo "Date = " . date_format($date, 'c');
```

Note that `$Date` was changed to `$date`, and since that's an object, the `date_format()` function is used to output a string. You can see it [working here](https://3v4l.org/uLNWm).

**As to the parse error**, there isn't one - so the culprit may be something in your config, or perhaps an issue saving the file to your development servier.

Your code as is won't really *work* but [this is the output it should give you](https://3v4l.org/YWlnl)- an `Undefined variable: Date` warning.

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason, I get the parse error on line 8.  (Incidentally, I fixed the $Date and $date issue and tested it and that still generated the parse error.)  However, when I added the date_format as you show on line 9, I no longer get the parse error on line 8.  So thank you, that fixed it.